# After upgrading to 17.10 all function keys map to "XF86WakeUp"

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, acpi, media-buttons, xev

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad E330 and just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 using Unity.
Before the upgrade there were no problems with my media keys but now they all seem to be mapped to "XF86WakeUp". However, on the ACPI level they seem to be ok.
When running `acpi_listen` the output for mute, VolDown and VolUp is correct:

```
$ acpi_list
button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000
button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
```

However, on `xev` the output is wrong:

```
$ xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
151 XF86WakeUp
151 XF86WakeUp
151 XF86WakeUp
```

The full output is the following:

```
$ xev
Outer window is 0x6200001, inner window is 0x6200002

PropertyNotify event, serial 8, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x27 (WM_NAME), time 16513838, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 9, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x22 (WM_COMMAND), time 16513838, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 10, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x28 (WM_NORMAL_HINTS), time 16513838, state PropertyNewValue

CreateNotify event, serial 11, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    parent 0x6200001, window 0x6200002, (10,10), width 50, height 50
border_width 4, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 14, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x151 (WM_PROTOCOLS), time 16513838, state PropertyNewValue

MapNotify event, serial 15, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200002, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x1bc (_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS), time 16513839, state PropertyNewValue

ConfigureNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200001, (0,0), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x4600017, override NO

ReparentNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200001, parent 0x1290641,
    (0,0), override NO

ConfigureNotify event, serial 29, synthetic YES, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200001, (55,24), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x0, override NO

ConfigureNotify event, serial 29, synthetic YES, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200001, (55,24), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x0, override NO

MapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200001, override NO

VisibilityNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    state VisibilityUnobscured

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    (0,0), width 178, height 10, count 3

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    (0,10), width 10, height 58, count 2

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    (68,10), width 110, height 58, count 1

Expose event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    (0,68), width 178, height 110, count 0

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x15f (_NET_WM_STATE), time 16513841, state PropertyNewValue

FocusIn event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  68  0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x159 (_NET_WM_DESKTOP), time 16513841, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x1c2 (WM_STATE), time 16513841, state PropertyNewValue

VisibilityNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    state VisibilityPartiallyObscured

ConfigureNotify event, serial 32, synthetic YES, window 0x6200001,
    event 0x6200001, window 0x6200001, (55,52), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x0, override NO

VisibilityNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    state VisibilityUnobscured

Expose event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    (168,0), width 10, height 140, count 1

Expose event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    (0,140), width 178, height 38, count 0

PropertyNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x1bc (_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS), time 16513844, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x156 (_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS), time 16513844, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x15f (_NET_WM_STATE), time 16513848, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x15f (_NET_WM_STATE), time 16513848, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x1bf (_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY), time 16513895, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x1bf (_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY), time 16513895, state PropertyNewValue

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16513915, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x1bf (_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY), time 16514495, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16515406, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967208 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   4294967168 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16516314, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16517461, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   4294967168 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16517885, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16518629, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   4294967168 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 16519033, (287,625), root:(342,677),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
    atom 0x15f (_NET_WM_STATE), time 16520695, state PropertyNewValue
```

If you need any further information to help me, I am happy to provide it.

Comment: Are you saying that all of your media keys are returning keycode 151?

Comment: yeah exactly. But in `acpi_list` they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me was disabling the `commands` plugin in `compiz-settings-manager`.

1. `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Open it - `ccsm`
3. Search for `commands`, un-check it, and close the manager.
4. Profit.

My function keys started working immediately without having to restart or anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I had a lot more difficulties coming up and, therefore, decided to erase my disk completely and go back to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS